Nestjs dto @IsEnum() validator is not working
i have a simple dto like this
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { IsEnum, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export enum Status {
  New = 'New',
  Old = 'Old',
}
export class UpdateStatusDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    enum: ContactStatus,
    description: 'User Status',
    required: true,
  })
  @IsEnum(Status)
  status: Status;
}

expected behaviour is to throw error when passing any other value than New or Old.
but not validating. how can i ensure the validation

If you've already ensured that and it's still not validating, there might be a Validation Pipe things you can check:
Validation Pipe: Make sure you have a validation pipe set up globally or scoped to your controller or method. You can set up a global validation pipe in your main.ts or app.module.ts file like this:
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();

This ensures that all incoming requests are validated against the defined DTOs.
